# Is there a decent alternative to dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

I am working on a c++ project, and facing a design issue currently. I would appreciate it if someone can give me some suggestions. Basically, I have a base class Base, and a subclass Derived as below. Class Derived can do something that class Base cannot do.

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual bool IsCapableOfDoingA() {return false;}
}

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
   bool IsCapableOfDoingA() {return true;}
   void DoA();
}
```

In another place where I have a pointer of type class Base.

```
void functionA(Base *pBase)
{
   if (pBase && pBase->IsCapableOfDoingA())
   {
      Derived *pDerived = static_cast<Derived*>(pBase);
      pDerived->DoA();
   }

}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `Base` and `Derived` that needs dynamic polymorphism in the first place? Without some context, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: In your question you ask for an alternative to `dynamic_cast`, but what's wrong with it?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without some more context.  But as you've guessed, you should almost certainly reconsider your design if you're in a situation where you need to query what member functions exist.

Comment: Is my impression or it should be static_cast<Derived*>(pBase) (with the pointer)?

Comment: Re dsign: you are right.

Comment: The pointer that I can get in functionA() points to a singleton object in my system that is responsible for configuring a specific hardware. Whether the object is of class Base or class Derived could vary for platforms. I don't want to use dynamic_cast, because it's costy in runntime. I was suggested to provide an virtual DoA() method in base class by default, but have it doing nothing. That's a good one. But providing a default implementation for Base class doesn't make too sense to me given the fact that it's not capable of doing A. So I believe there must exist a better solution.

Comment: Do you know at compile-time which kind of hardware you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, no idea about the hardware at compile-time. I have a factory class that instantiates a Base or Derived class object based on hardware in running time.

Comment: Can you just make a public virtual `configure()` function, and let each subclass decide how best to do that?  If it involves doing `A`, then those that can, will.

Comment: @Kevin : The fundamental question that you have yet to answer is: why do you need dynamic polymorphism in the first place? `Base` appears to be 100% useless as you've shown it.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to add the function to the base class.

```
virtual void DoA() { throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented"); }
```

Comment: Depends - if it's reasonable and common to do nothing, I'd just write `virtual void DoA() {}`. Note that the question doesn't contain a `throw` in an `else` branch.

Answer (score 2):

In your design, is it ok for `DoA` to return a success code of some sort?  You could replace `IsCapableOfDoingA` with `DoA` itself, and have the Base version simply return false (or other suitable error code).  Child objects capable of doing `A` can override this function with a proper implementation.

You're right that `dynamic_cast` is often a design smell.  With some more context we might be able to provide a better answer.  My first thought is to really make sure a `Derived` IS-A `Base` if you're going to be polymorphically asking `Base`s for things they might not be able to do.

Comment: It's ok for Base to return a false since it's not capable of doing A. But since Base is not capable of doing A, I am figuring if it really makes sense to provide this interface to Base. IIRC, it's design problem discussed in book "Effect C++". The author gave an example that a Bird can fly or cannot. So it's better to not provide a fly() for class Bird, But derive a subclass FlyableBird that has a fly() member method.

Comment: Yep, it's Item #32 from the 3rd edition of _Effective C++_.  Scott gives suggestions ([Mark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300547/46821) being one of them) but no absolute right answers.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic_cast will return NULL if the object doesn't have the appropriate type (assuming that the base class defines at least one virtual method -- usually you should at least make the base class's destructor virtual).  So you can use the following idiom:

```
void functionA(Base *pBase)
{
   if (Derived *pDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pBase)) {
      pDerived->DoA();
   }    
}
```

If pBase doesn't have type Derived, then pDerived will be 0 (false), so the body of the if statement will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea. You can split the enhanced functions into an interface and have a method to return the interface pointer.

```
class InterfaceA
{
public:
    virtual ~InterfaceA() {}
    virtual void DoA() = 0;
};

class Base
{
public:
   virtual InterfaceA* GetAInterface() {return NULL;}
};

class Derived: public Base, InterfaceA
{
public:
   InterfaceA* GetAInterface() {return this;}
   void DoA();
};

void functionA(Base *pBase)
{
   InterfaceA* pA = pBase ? pBase->GetAInterface() : NULL;
   if (pA)
      pA->DoA();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your suggestions. static_cast is not needed in your solution.